# Vuejs Routes children links

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

How to create a nested route correctly?

```js
const CarTable = { template: '<div>Car List</div>' }
const CarShow = { template: '<div>Car Show</div>' }
const CarCreate = { template: '<div>Car Create</div>'}


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/car', component: CarTable,
      children: [
        {path: 'show', component: CarShow},
        {path: 'create', component: CarCreate}
      ]
}
]
})
  
  const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

```css
a {
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: Red;
}
a + a {
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <p>
    <router-link to="/car">List Car</router-link>
    <router-link to="/car/show">Car Show</router-link>
    <router-link to="/car/create">Car Create</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

The transition to the main category occurs :8000/car, but the nested category does not :8000/car/show, :8000/car/create

Comment: You spelled the `children` incorrectly while defining.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari, Thanks, corrected, but still doesn't work.

Comment: The curly bracket is not closed in this line `{path: '/car', component: CarTable,`, it should be something like `{path: '/car', component: CarTable}, children`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [vue-router doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html), nested routes allow to display **nested** components ; e.g. adding `<router-view></router-view>` to your `CarTable` component template will display the children.
However I am not sure nested routes is what you want to achieve, if you want top level, tab-like components, juste use different routes such as

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: '/car', component: CarTable},
        {path: '/car/show', component: CarShow},
        {path: '/car/create', component: CarCreate}
    ]
})
```

See the below snippet for a nested routes working example

```js
const CarTable = { template: '<div><div>Car List</div><router-view></router-view></div>' }
const CarShow = { template: '<div>Car Show</div>' }
const CarCreate = { template: '<div>Car Create</div>'}


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/car', component: CarTable,
      children: [
        {path: 'show', component: CarShow},
        {path: 'create', component: CarCreate}
      ]
}
]
})
  
  const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

```css
a {
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: Red;
}
a + a {
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <p>
    <router-link to="/car">List Car</router-link>
    <router-link to="/car/show">Car Show</router-link>
    <router-link to="/car/create">Car Create</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```